# Get the both "ID" and "HREF" attributes and create a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a dinamically generated code as follows which lists some files and let the user delete them by clicking on their links:

```
<div id="filenames">
    <div>
        <a id="1" class="delete" href="#1984.xls">1984.xls
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="2" class="delete" href="#1984.xml">1984.xml
    </div>
</div>
```

Each file has its ID. The list is generated via AJAX when the user uploads the files.

When the user clicks a link, before the file is passed to the "delete.php" call, I would like to have a JSON object that lists all the files like this:

```
{1 : 1984.xls, 2 : 1984.xml}
```

I managed to made it using an array

```
var files = [];

$('#filenames').find('a').each(function() {
    files.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

But this simply adds to the array the name of the file which is stored inside `href`.

I don't know how to `find` both `id` and `attr` and create instead of an array a JSON object as said above.

Comment: Are you pointing `key` of object as `id` of element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an `object` using `{}` (and not `array` `[]`) then affect the `key:value` to it as `files[key] = value` when the `key` is the `id` of the link and `value` represented by the `href`, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
var files = {};

$('#filenames').find('a').each(function() {
  var key = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).attr('href');

  files[key] = value;
});

console.log(files);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filenames">
    <div>
        <a id="1" class="delete" href="#1984.xls">1984.xls
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="2" class="delete" href="#1984.xml">1984.xml
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in following way:

```js
var files = {};

$('#filenames').find('a').each(function() {
    files[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('href');
});

console.log(files);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filenames">
    <div>
        <a id="1" class="delete" href="#1984.xls">1984.xls
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="2" class="delete" href="#1984.xml">1984.xml
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use [**`bracket-notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) to assign value to the object when `key` is dynamic!

Initialize `files` as `object({})`, not as `array` as you are expecting result as an `object`

***Note:*** Use `.substr(1);` if you are suppose to remove `#(first character)` from string.

```js
var files = {};
$('#filenames').find('a').each(function(i) {
  //files[i] = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);;//For index iteration as key
  files[this.id] = $(this).attr('href').substr(1); //For ID attribute as key
});
console.log(files);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filenames">
  <div>
    <a id="1" class="delete" href="#1984.xls">1984.xls</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="2" class="delete" href="#1984.xml">1984.xml</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var files = [];
item = {}
$('#filenames').find('a').each(function () {
    item[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('href');

});
files.push(item);
console.log(files);
```